# Quaternionification isomorphims

Tags: representation-theory, quaternions

In the book **Representation of compact Lie Groups** of Tammo tom Dieck, chapter II.6, it is explained that if $V$ is a complex vector space and $W$ a quaternionic module, we have the isomorphisms (where the index is for the restriction of scalars)
$$(\mathbb{H}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V)_{\mathbb{C}}\cong V\oplus \overline{V}$$
and
$$\mathbb{H}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}W_{\mathbb{C}}\cong W\oplus W$$
The first ${\mathbb{C}}$-isomorphism is given as
$$(z_1+j z_2)\otimes v\to z_1 v\oplus z_2 v$$
where $\mathbb{H}$ is considered as a right ${\mathbb{C}}$-module. I fail to see why it works.

**Edit**

Actually I finally understand why it works like that, and no other way.

I had to go back to the Wikipedia definition of a change of ring, or of the tensor product of a $\mathbb{C}$-module with a $(\mathbb{H}, \mathbb{C})$-bimodule, which is a $\mathbb{H}$-module.

It is necessary to consider such structure if we want any action coming from the quaternionic action of the group on $\mathbb{H}\otimes V$ to commute with its structure as a $\mathbb{C}$-module.

It means here that $\mathbb{H}$ is considered as a right $\mathbb{C}$-module and as a left $\mathbb{H}$-module over itself. Then $\mathbb{H}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V$ is actually a $\mathbb{H}$-module where the multiplication by a quaternion $q'$ of $q\otimes v$ is $(q'q)\otimes v$. So the isomorphism given is a $\mathbb{C}$-isomorphism if $z_2v$ is considered an element of $\overline{V}$.

So only the following question remains:

**End of Edit**

And what is the second $\mathbb{H}$-isomorphism of $\mathbb{H}$-modules?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for the hint (+1). But even with it I have difficulty, because of some confusion with considering H as a right C-module or left, and which one?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think the same confusion makes me fail to see why the first isomorphism works ...

Comment: The name of the author is Tammo tom Dieck.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for correcting my disrespectful and stupid mistake (+1)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez did I get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got it now, but unfortunately it was more by hand than by a sound reasoning like in the case of complexification and de-complexication, where we looked for the eigenvalue of the complex structure.

So the second isomorphism that works seems to be, if $\mathbb{H}$ is always considered as a $(\mathbb{H}, \mathbb{C})$-bimodule, for $q\in\mathbb{H}$ and $w\in W_{\mathbb{C}}$
$$q\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} w\to q w\oplus q i w$$
The reciprocal of this isomorphism $W\oplus W\to \mathbb{H}\otimes W_{\mathbb{C}}$ is, for $v, w\in W$
$$(v, w)\to\frac12(1\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} v-j\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} j v)+\frac{i}2(1\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} w+j\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} j w)$$
The isomorphism is clearly $\mathbb{H}$-linear.

If somebody can validate my answer and give me a more systematic way of reasoning and / or reference about it, I will give him the bounty and considered his answer as accepted.